# Access specific key/value pairs with keyvalue pipe

Tags: angular, object, pipe

I am using keyvalue pipe in Angular 11 for looping through the object I get form an Http Request. The problem is that in my template I only want to show specific key-value pairs and not what the whole object contains.

For example I have this object:

````
agreedToTermsOfUse: true
comments: ""
companyId: "20097"
contactId: "20127"
createDate: 1617793054388
ctCollectionId: "0"
defaultUser: false
emailAddressVerified: true
externalReferenceCode: ""
facebookId: "0"```

and I only want to show companyId and contactId.

The code in my template is the following: 

<button type="button" (click)="getData()">Click me</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of dataObject | keyvalue">
    <b>{{item.key}}</b> : {{item.value}}
</div>

and shows the whole content of the object.
````

Answer (score 1):

You dont need *ngFor loop then...
Just print

```
{{dataObject.companyId}} {{dataObject.contactId}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing object properties is probably simpler, but if you still want to use a *ngFor loop create a custom pipe that transforms the object to an array and filters the keys you want

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

interface IKeyValuePair {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

const validKeys = ['companyId', 'contactId'];

@Pipe({
  name: 'keyValueFilter'
})
export class KeyValueFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): Array<IKeyValuePair> {
    return Object.keys(value).reduce((acc: Array<IKeyValuePair>, key) => {
      if (validKeys.includes(key)) {
        acc.push({ key, value: value[key] });
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dataObject | keyValueFilter">
  <b>{{item.key}}</b> : {{item.value}}
</div>
```